# How do i replace an asked for item in a dictionary

Tags: python

My problem is that I want to be able to specify a subject, then using the old grade, enter in a new grade, and print out the result.

I've tried doing it using `dicname.update({subject : subjects.replace(old_grade, new_grade)})`. but it don't seem to work in my favor.

```
emner = {"INFO100":"C", "INFO104":"B", "ECON100":"B"}
```

class eksamensResultater:

```
def settKarakter(values):
    vilket_fag = input('Hva er navnet på faget: ')
    gammel_karakter = input('Hva er den gamle karakteren: ')
    ny_karakter = input('Hva er den nye karakteren: ')
    global emner
    for i in values:
        for v in values[i]:
            if vilket_fag in v:
                emner.update(INFO100 = ny_karakter)
                print(i, emner[i])
            else:
                print('Hei')
```

the expected the result is:

```
INFO100 (the chosen grade)
INFO104 B
ECON100 B
```

Comment: `emner["INFO100"] = chosen grade`?

Comment: Can you show how you would call the function to achieve your desired result?

Comment: Ive tried both of the answers below, but for some reason, the value will still not change

Comment: Please show an example of actual input and output: what arguments are you passing in, and what result are you getting out?

Comment: the expected output is practicly showed in the thread. but im changing the code, a bit, because a problem occured

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the **replace()** method in order to change a value

Simply just do:

```
emner = {"INFO100":"C", "INFO104":"B", "ECON100":"B"}

emner.update(INFO100 = 'New')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'INFO100': 'New', 'INFO104': 'B', 'ECON100': 'B'}
```

Comment: when i try this, the change dont actually print out when i run my program

Comment: its gotta change, did you make sure that there are no differences in letter cases?
For i.e if you try (info100 = 'newvalue') its not going to change since the original is INFO100

Answer (score 0):

This is how you update a dictionary key value:

```
emner = {"INFO100":"C", "INFO104":"B", "ECON100":"B"}
emner['INFO100'] = "A"
print(emner)
```

You can do it like this if you want it more flexible in function:

```
emner = {"INFO100": "C", "INFO104": "B", "ECON100": "B"}


def update_emner(subject, grade):
    emner[subject] = grade


update_emner('INFO100', "A")
print(emner)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the old grade. Just the new grade and i think you forget in your class the self argument in the method. I added two lines creating an object and calling the function, just to check it.

```
emner = {"INFO100":"C", "INFO104":"B", "ECON100":"B"}

class eksamensResultater:

    def settKarakter(self, hvilke_fag, ny_karakter):
        for i in emner:
            if hvilke_fag in emner:
                emner[hvilke_fag] = ny_karakter
                print(i, emner[i])
            else:
                print(i, emner[i])

# Just checking the results
newObject = eksamensResultater()
newObject.settKarakter("INFO100", "D")
```